# Make a password input in tkinter with show password option

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create an Entry widget in tkinter to write a passsword. I used `password.config(show = "*")` and it works fine. Is there a way to disable this configuretion and make the widget to show me what I typed ? I'd like to make this happen when press a button

Answer (score 0):

`password.config(show = "")` will make the password visible again.

So you can make a function that toggles between `password.config(show = "*")` and `password.config(show = "")` to hide and show the password.

Here's a quick program using a checkbutton that illustrates this:

```
import tkinter as tk
def toggle():
    global password, checkbutton
    if checkbutton.var.get():
        password.config(show = "*")
    else:
        password.config(show = "")


root = tk.Tk()
password = tk.Entry(root)
password.default_show_val = password.config(show = "*")
password.config(show = "*")
checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Show password", onvalue=False, offvalue=True, command=toggle)
checkbutton.var = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
checkbutton['variable'] = checkbutton.var
password.pack()
checkbutton.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

**Output**

Hidden:
[image]

Shown:
[image]